Gitlab contributor analytics across all projects
I need to see commits, merge request analytics or dashboard across all projects on Gitlab. I can see all of these analytics under analyze menu when I entered into the specific project. However there isn't any contributor analytics on the group or admin level.
Any help will be appreciated.
